# What happened to Sandra's mother in "Sandra and Woo" webcomic?

Tags: webcomics, sandra-and-woo

The webcomic's ["Cast" page](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/cast/) says that her father Richard North is a "single father".

Did the comic (or the author) ever explain what happened to her mother?

(The reason I'm asking: one of the comments to the latest big reveal strip compared Larisa's fate to what happened to Sandra's mother but I don't know if that was just a random guess or based on specific information about the latter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, no information has been given on that front in the strip itself. All that we know is that [Julie North died on June 14th 2006](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2009/01/15/0025-an-overdue-visit/) at the age of 33, about two years before the comic strips started. I haven't found the comment likening Larisa's condition to Sandra's mother's death. Could you provide a quote and/or a link?

Outside the strip, in [a Q&A](http://www.sandraandwoo.com/2015/05/04/ask-novil-questions-about-sandra-and-woo/comment-page-2/#comment-110768), the author said, in response to a question as to whether we'd ever learn how Sandra's mother died:

> Maybe. I currently favor a car accident as cause of death, but that can be changed in the comic if needed.

So, until he establishes the answer inside the comic, it looks like a car accident is indeed the right answer.

Comment: Quote (I may have misinterpreted): "Somehow I imagine Sandra’s mom was a person like Larissa"

Comment: Update! Turns out that the author said in a Q&A that his current idea is that it was a car accident, but that he reserves the right to change his mind in the future.